# How to transmit location information with Android Beacon Library

Tags: ibeacon-android

I want to use something similar to
[beacon-transmitter sample code](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter.html)
to **transmit location information in a custom [LocationBeacon](http://pastebin.com/x4Dp28w9)**.

From the sample code, it seems I must also create a custom `BeaconParser` using `BeaconParser.setBeaconLayout` to be able to parse the additional location information that I want to transmit.

**How should I write the beaconLayout String to parse location information for my `LocationBeacon`?**

Assume that what I want to do is possible, but, is this a recommended/proper way to use beacons? (I want a cell-phone to "broadcast" my location using beacons)

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible.

There are only 26 bytes of advertising space to work with and 5 of these need to be reserved for the company code (2 bytes) and your custom beacon identifier (2 bytes) and a transmitter power calibration value (1 byte).   This leaves you with 21 bytes to work with to store latitude, longitude and any other information you want to transmit.  You'll probably also want to transmit a device identifier so if multiple phones are broadcasting their location you know which is which.

Here's a proposed layout:

```
BeaconParser p = new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=10ca,i:4-9,i:10-13,i:14-17,p:18-18");
```

This is made up of:

1. A two byte beacon type code 0x10ca (reads like "loca"tion, clever eh?)
2. A six byte mobile device identifier.  You could make it a simple sequential number, or use the mac address of the mobile device.
3. A 4-byte identifier field for the latitude.
4. A 4-byte identifier field for the longitude.
5. A 1-byte transmitter power calibration constant.

You can then transmit as this beacon like this.  Note that you have to convert the floating point latitude and longitude numbers to unsigned integers for them to work as identifiers:

```
double latitude = 38.93;
double longitude = -77.23;
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
            .setManufacturer(0x0118) // Radius Networks
            .setId1("1") // device sequence number
            .setId2(String.format("0x%X", (long)((latitude+90)*10000.0)))
            .setId3(String.format("0x%X", (long)((longitude+180)*10000.0)))
            .setTxPower(-59) // The measured transmitter power at one meter in dBm
            .build();
BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser); 
beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
```

You can then detect beacons like this and read out the values like so:

```
double latitude = Long.parseLong(beacon.getId2().toString().substring(2), 16) / 10000.0 - 90.0;
double longitude = Long.parseLong(beacon.getId3().toString().substring(2), 16) / 10000.0 - 180.0;
```

Some might note that transmitting a device's latitude and longitude over the 50 meter range of bluetooth is a little obvious, because all receiving devices are essentially at the same latitude and longitude, too.  But it is still a good exercise to show how beacon parsers work.